# Automatic getting atrribute to polygons : label name of polygon that shape is inside or overlaped

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator

I have many polygons in my merged shapefile (all  in my country boundary) that I want to add them field (in attribute table) :label name of the province that contains them. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: and please think about if some boundary of polygons are between 2 or more province

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Spatial Join.  In particular, read this article about how to use the 'join' merge rule to capture multiple overlapping zones and store them in one field.

https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help